# SwashBuckle Customising Operation Tags

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm simply looking to remove the word controller from appearing in the swagger documentation. I've looked at using an IOperationFilter or IDocumentFilter to manually edit the tags, but the properties are read-only.

```
/// <summary>
/// Home
/// </summary>
public class HomeController : ApiController
{

}
```

I've enabled XmlComments as per documentation on GitHub.  I don't have any other problem other than i dont have the ability to change the descriptions for a Controller.

```
 private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
 {
     return string.Format(@"{0}\bin\Sample.WebApi.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
 }
```

And in the Swaggerconfig :-

```
 c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean removing "controller" from the list of action groups (the default of which is the controller name) then in your SwaggerConfig.cs you can use the GroupActionsBy option:

```
c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc =>
{
    return apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.Replace("Controller", "");
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!